# Traversal of Bounding Volume Hierachy in Shaders

Tags: glsl, compiler-optimization, vulkan, raytracing, bounding-box

I am working on a path tracer using vulkan compute shaders. I implemented a tree representing a [bounding volume hierachy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy). The idea of the BVH is to minimize the amount of objects a ray intersection test needs to be performed on.

---

**#1 Naive Implementation**

My first implementation is very fast, it traverses the tree down to a *single* leaf of the BVH tree. However, the ray might intersect *multiple* leaves. This code then leads to some triangles not being rendered (although they should).

```
int box_index = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < boxes_count; i++) {
    // the first box has no parent, boxes[0].parent is set to -1
    if (boxes[i].parent == box_index) {
        if (intersect_box(boxes[i], ray)) {
            box_index = i;
        }
    }
}

if (box_index > -1) {
    uint a = boxes[box_index].ids_offset;
    uint b = a + boxes[box_index].ids_count;

    for (uint j = a; j < b; j++) {
        uint triangle_id = triangle_references[j];
        // triangle intersection code ...
    }
}
```

---

**#2 Multi-Leaf Implementation**

My second implementation accounts for the fact that multiple leaves might be intersected. However, this implementation is ***36x*** slower than implementation #1 (okay, I miss some intersection tests in #1, but still...).

```
bool[boxes.length()] hits;
hits[0] = intersect_box(boxes[0], ray);

for (int i = 1; i < boxes_count; i++) {
    if (hits[boxes[i].parent]) {
        hits[i] = intersect_box(boxes[i], ray);
    } else {
        hits[i] = false;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < boxes_count; i++) {
    if (!hits[i]) {
        continue;
    }

    // only leaves have ids_offset and ids_count defined (not set to -1)
    if (boxes[i].ids_offset < 0) {
        continue;
    }

    uint a = boxes[i].ids_offset;
    uint b = a + boxes[i].ids_count;

    for (uint j = a; j < b; j++) {
        uint triangle_id = triangle_references[j];
        // triangle intersection code ...
    }
}
```

---

This performance difference drives me crazy. It seems only having a single statement like `if(dynamically_modified_array[some_index])` has a huge impact on performance. I suspect that the SPIR-V or GPU compiler is no longer able to do its optimization magic? So here are my questions:

1. Is this indeed an optimization problem?
2. If yes, can I transform implementation #2 to be better optimizable?
   Can I somehow give optimization hints?
3. Is there a standard way to implement BVH tree queries in shaders?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some digging, I found a solution. Important to understand is that the BVH tree does not exclude the possibility that one needs to evaluate *all* leaves.

Implementation #3 below, uses hit and miss links. The boxes need to be sorted in a way that in the worst case all of them are queried in the correct order (so a single loop is enough). However, links are used to skip nodes which don't need to be evaluated. When the current node is a leaf node, the actual triangle intersections are performed.

- hit link ~ which node to jump to in case of a hit (green below)
- miss link ~ which node to jump to in case of a miss (red below)

[image: BVH tree evaluation order]

Image taken from [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ethachisu/tdf2015.pdf). The associated paper and source code is also on Prof. Toshiya Hachisuka's [page](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ethachisu/). The same concept is also described in [this paper referenced in the slides](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2018/course/TDA362/EfficiencyIssuesForRayTracing.pdf).

---

**#3 BVH Tree with Hit and Miss Links**

I had to extend the data which is pushed to the shader with the links. Also some offline fiddling was required to store the tree correctly. At first I tried using a while loop (loop until `box_index_next` is -1) which resulted in a crazy slowdown again. Anyway, the following works reasonably fast:

```
int box_index_next = 0;

for (int box_index = 0; box_index < boxes_count; box_index++) {
    if (box_index != box_index_next) {
        continue;
    }

    bool hit = intersect_box(boxes[box_index], ray);
    bool leaf = boxes[box_index].ids_count > 0;

    if (hit) {
        box_index_next = boxes[box_index].links.x; // hit link
    } else {
        box_index_next = boxes[box_index].links.y; // miss link
    }

    if (hit && leaf) {
        uint a = boxes[box_index].ids_offset;
        uint b = a + boxes[box_index].ids_count;

        for (uint j = a; j < b; j++) {
            uint triangle_id = triangle_references[j];
            // triangle intersection code ...
        }
    }
}
```

---

This code is about 3x slower than the fast, but flawed implementation #1. This is somewhat expected, now the speed depends on the actual tree, not on the gpu optimization. Consider, for example, a degenerate case where triangles are aligned along an axis: a ray in the same direction might intersect with all triangles, then all tree leaves need to be evaluated.

Prof. Toshiya Hachisuka proposes a further optimization for such cases [in his sildes](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ethachisu/tdf2015.pdf) (page 36 and onward): One stores multiple versions of the BVH tree, spatially sorted along x, -x, y, -y, z and -z. For traversal the correct version needs to be selected based on the ray. Then one can stop the traversal as soon as a triangle from a leaf is intersected, since all remaining nodes to be visited will be spatially behind this node (from the ray point of view).

---

Once the BVH tree is built, finding the links is quite straightforward (some python code below):

```
class NodeAABB(object):

    def __init__(self, obj_bounds, obj_ids):
        self.children = [None, None]
        self.obj_bounds = obj_bounds
        self.obj_ids = obj_ids

    def split(self):
        # split recursively and create children here
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def is_leaf(self):
        return set(self.children) == {None}

    def build_links(self, next_right_node=None):
        if not self.is_leaf():
            child1, child2 = self.children

            self.hit_node = child1
            self.miss_node = next_right_node

            child1.build_links(next_right_node=child2)
            child2.build_links(next_right_node=next_right_node)

        else:
            self.hit_node = next_right_node
            self.miss_node = self.hit_node

    def collect(self):
        # retrieve in depth first fashion for correct order
        yield self
        if not self.is_leaf():
            child1, child2 = self.children
            yield from child1.collect()
            yield from child2.collect()
```

After you store all AABBs in an array (which will be sent to the GPU) you can use `hit_node` and `miss_node` to look up the indices for the links and store them as well.

Comment: Can you tell me how you calculated the links.x and links.y during the tree construction?

Comment: I added some sample code, hope that helps. In my case links is an ivec2.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: In case of defining the next_right_node of a node, how can you determine the position in the array? I can't see where it is.

Comment: I did not write that in the code above. In build_links the respective node objects are stored as reference. Once this is done put all nodes in an array with collect(), afterwards you can determine the index, e.g.: all_my_nodes.index(some_node.hit_node)