# Why does the bounding box appear around the object in a strange way?

Tags: opengl, glsl, raytracing, bounding-box, bounding-volume

I am creating an OpenGL based ray tracer for polygon models. The basic structure is about to render the results to a quad from the fragment shader. To accelerate the application, BVH-trees are used. Because there is no recursion in GLSL, I decided to find an other way to traverse the bounding boxes. The bvh nodes (including the boxes) and the primitive coordinates are sent to the fragment shader into a shader storage buffer.

I am using the basic idea described in: [Threaded BVH-tree traversal in shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479683/traversal-of-bounding-volume-hierachy-in-shaders)

The above solution uses links "*which are used to skip nodes which don't need to be evaluated*".
There is a hit link: which node to jump to in case of a hit and there is a miss link: which node to jump to in case of a miss.

Actually, I am not using links to navigate between the boxes, as I have a complete binary tree, which makes easier to navigate between the different depths. But the basic concept is similar to link above. I store the nodes in breadth-first order.

Unfortunately, when the program is running there is a weird result. I can see the object partly ray-traced and the bounding box as well. The bounding box has grey color, but this color should be the color of the background.

The below picture shows the current state. You should see a cone in a grey background, but instead of this you can see a grey bounding box around its object.
[image]

... and how it should look like (it is a non bvh-tree version)

[image]

Here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 460 core

layout(std140, binding=0) buffer primitives{
    vec3 primitiveCoordinates[];
};

struct FlatBvhNode   //I checked the data and it works fine.
{
                      // base aligment   aligned offset
    vec4 min;         // 16 byte                 0
    vec4 max;         // 16 byte                16
    int  order;       // 4 byte                 32
    int  isLeaf;      // 4 byte                 36
    int  createdEmpty;// 4 byte                 40  //it is because of the complete binary tree
    int  leftOrRight; // 4 byte                 44
    vec4 indices[10];// 32 byte                 48
};

layout(std430, binding=2) buffer TNodes
{
    FlatBvhNode nodes[];   // the nodes of the tree in breadth-first order
};

out vec4 FragColor;
in vec3 p;
uniform vec3 wEye;

struct Light{
    vec3 Le, La;
    vec3 direction;
    vec3 position;
};

uniform Light lights[];

struct Ray{
    vec3 orig, dir;
};

struct Hit{
    vec3 orig, dir, normal;
    float t;
};


Hit rayTriangleIntersect(Ray ray, vec3 v0, vec3 v1, vec3 v2){
    // This works well, so I don't include.
}

vec3 getCoordinatefromIndices(float index){
    return primitiveCoordinates[int(index)];
}


Hit firstIntersect(Ray ray, int i){
    Hit besthit;
    besthit.t=-1;
    for (int j=0;j<nodes[i].indices.length();j++){
        vec3 TrianglePointA=getCoordinatefromIndices(nodes[i].indices[j].x);
        vec3 TrianglePointB=getCoordinatefromIndices(nodes[i].indices[j].y);
        vec3 TrianglePointC=getCoordinatefromIndices(nodes[i].indices[j].z);
        Hit hit=rayTriangleIntersect(ray, TrianglePointA, TrianglePointB, TrianglePointC);

        if (hit.t==-1){ continue; }

        if (hit.t>0 && (besthit.t>hit.t || besthit.t<0)){
            besthit=hit;
        }
    }
    return besthit;
}


bool rayIntersectWithBox(const vec4 boxMin, const vec4 boxMax, const Ray r) {
    vec3 invdir = 1.0 / r.dir.xyz;
    const vec3 f = (boxMax.xyz - r.orig.xyz) * invdir;
    const vec3 n = (boxMin.xyz - r.orig.xyz) * invdir;

    const vec3 tmax = max(f, n);
    const vec3 tmin = min(f, n);

    const float t1 = min(tmax.x, min(tmax.y, tmax.z));
    const float t0 = max(max(tmin.x, max(tmin.y, tmin.z)), 0.0f);

    return t1 >= t0;
}



//This is where should be the problem.
//This is the method responsible for evaluating the bboxes.
//Instead of the links I can reach the childs with 2*i+1 or 2*i+2 and I can also get the parent 
//with an inverse (int(ceil(i-2)/2))

    Hit traverseBvhNode(Ray ray, FlatBvhNode node){
        Hit result;

    int next = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length(); i++) {
        if (i != next) {   continue;  }

        bool hit = rayIntersectWithBox(nodes[i].min, nodes[i].max, ray);

        if (nodes[i].createdEmpty==1){ hit=false;} 

        if (hit) {
            if (nodes[i].isLeaf==1 && nodes[i].createdEmpty!=1){ return firstIntersect(ray, i);}
            next = 2*i+1;
        }

        else if (!hit) {

            if (nodes[i].leftOrRight==0){ next = i+1; }
            else if (nodes[i].leftOrRight==1){ next = int(ceil(i-2)/2);
                if (next==5){
                    result.t=-1;
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}


Hit traverseBvhTree(Ray ray){
    Hit hit;
    if (rayIntersectWithBox(nodes[0].min, nodes[0].max, ray)){
        return traverseBvhNode(ray, nodes[0]);
    }
    return hit;
}

vec3 trace(Ray ray){
    vec3 color= vec3(0, 0, 0);
    vec3 ka= vec3(0.135, 0.2225, 0.1575);
    vec3 kd= vec3(0.54, 0.89, 0.63);

    Hit hit=traverseBvhTree(ray);

    if (hit.t==-1){ return lights[0].La; }

    color=lights[0].La*ka;

// The below part is under contruction, but functions well.
        Ray shadowRay;
        shadowRay.orig=hit.orig+hit.normal*0.001f;
        shadowRay.dir=lights[0].direction;
        float cosTheta = dot(hit.normal, lights[0].direction)/(length(hit.normal)*length(lights[0].direction));
        if (cosTheta > 0){
            color+=lights[0].Le*cosTheta*kd;
            float cosDelta=dot(hit.normal, normalize(-ray.dir + lights[0].direction));
            if (cosDelta>0){
                color=color+lights[0].Le*vec3(0.316228, 0.316228, 0.316228)*pow(0.1, cosDelta);
            }
        }
        return color;
    }

void main()
{
    Ray ray;
    ray.orig = wEye;
    ray.dir = normalize(p - wEye);
    FragColor = vec4(trace(ray), 1);

}
```

Any help is well appreciated.

---

### Update 1:

I used Rabbid76's advice and modified the `rayIntersectWithBox` method's return statement from `return t1 >= t0;` to `return tmin.x < tmax.x && tmin.y < tmax.y && tmin.z < tmax.z;`

As you can see in the snapshot, there is no visible bounding box, but the object still has some troubles.

[image]

---

### Update 2:

I updated the `traverseBvhNode` of fragment shader's code. I am sure the algorithm traverses all the nodes now, as I checked if `i==nodes.length()` and it gives true.

Unfortunately, the result in the window is still the same as in my last update.

Here are the modifcations of `traverseBvhNode` method:

1. For simplicity I put the content of `firstIntersection` method to `traverseBvhNode` method.
2. Moreover, I move the `return besthit` line to the end of
   traverseBvhNode method, because I have to traverse all nodes before
   returning with the best intersection.
3. I also modified the for cycle to a while cycle, as with `while` I can modify the value of `i` in the block, whereas for does not permit this kind of action.
4. Because there are some `continue` instructions as well in the `traverseBvhNode` method, I put the `i++` instruction at the beginning of the method.

Here is the updated code:

```
Hit traverseBvhNode(Ray ray, FlatBvhNode node){
    Hit besthit;
    besthit.t=-1;

    int db=0;
    Hit hitreal;

    int next = 0;
    int i=-1;
    while(i<=nodes.length()) {
        i++;

        if(i >nodes.length()){ break;}
        if (i != next) { continue; }

        bool hit = rayIntersectWithBox(nodes[i].min, nodes[i].max, ray);

        if (nodes[i].createdEmpty==1){ hit=false; }

        if (hit) {

            if (nodes[i].isLeaf==1 && nodes[i].createdEmpty!=1){
                db++;

                for (int j=0;j<nodes[i].indices.length();j++){
                    if (mod(nodes[i].indices[j].x, 1)==0 && mod(nodes[i].indices[j].y, 1)==0 && mod(nodes[i].indices[j].z, 1)==0){

                        vec3 TrianglePointA=getCoordinatefromIndices(nodes[i].indices[j].x).xyz;
                        vec3 TrianglePointB=getCoordinatefromIndices(nodes[i].indices[j].y).xyz;
                        vec3 TrianglePointC=getCoordinatefromIndices(nodes[i].indices[j].z).xyz;

                        hitreal=rayTriangleIntersect(ray, TrianglePointA, TrianglePointB, TrianglePointC);

                        if (hitreal.t==-1){ continue; }

                        if (hitreal.t>0 && (besthit.t>hitreal.t || besthit.t<0)){
                            besthit=hitreal;
                        }
                    }
                    else{ continue;}
                }
            }
            else{ next = 2*i+1;}
        }

        else  {
            if (nodes[i].leftOrRight==0){  next = i+1; }

            else if (nodes[i].leftOrRight==1){

                int id=int(ceil(i-2)/2);
                FlatBvhNode parent=nodes[id];

                while(parent.leftOrRight==1){
                    parent=nodes[int(ceil(parent.order-2)/2)];
                }
                next = parent.order+1;
                i=next-1;
            }
        }
    }
    return besthit;
}
```

Comment: It looks like, the ray intersecting the bounding box and that is why we can see the box, but it is completely impossible as I am checking intersections related to the triangles of the bvh leaf nodes. I also checked, if there is a memory alignment problem, but it is not.

Comment: I'm not sure about the algorithm in `rayIntersectWithBox`. Can you try `return tmin.x < tmax.x && tmin.y < tmax.y && tmin.z < tmax.z;` instead of `return t1 >= t0;`?

Comment: Thanks man! It is a bit better now. I uploaded a snapshot.

Comment: I guess, there is something with the layout of the FlatBvhNode. The last member of the FlastBvhNode struct is the indices array, where I store the indexes of the primitve coordinates. But actually, the number of the indices per node are different. Unfortunately I could not give a dynamic array to the type of this array. So maybe in the firstIntersection method I intersect non-exeisting triangles as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the traversal of bounding volume tree was bleeding from several faults besides, I had also update the `rayIntersectionWithBox` method (Thanks flying to Rabbid76)

So here is the bvh traversal method and the `rayIntersectWithBox`. I also moved the `firstintersection` method into the traversal method.
My solution is similar to this: [Threaded-Bvh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479683/traversal-of-bounding-volume-hierachy-in-shaders), except I didn't use predefined links in the nodes. I used breadth-first algorithm to reach the parent or the child nodes.

```
bool rayIntersectWithBox(vec4 boxMin, vec4 boxMax, Ray r) {
    vec3 invdir = 1.0 / r.dir.xyz;
    vec3 f = (boxMax.xyz - r.orig.xyz) * invdir;
    vec3 n = (boxMin.xyz - r.orig.xyz) * invdir;

    vec3 tmax = f * sign(invdir);
    vec3 tmin = n * sign(invdir);

    return tmin.x < tmax.x && tmin.y < tmax.y && tmin.z < tmax.z;
}

Hit traverseBvhNode(Ray ray, FlatBvhNode node){
    Hit besthit;
    besthit.t=-1;
    bool hit;
    Hit hitreal;
    int i=0;

    while (i<=nodes.length()) {

        if (nodes[i].isLeaf==1){
            for (int j=0;j<nodes[i].indices.length();j++){
                if (mod(nodes[i].indices[j].x, 1)==0 && mod(nodes[i].indices[j].y, 1)==0 && mod(nodes[i].indices[j].z, 1)==0){
                    vec3 TrianglePointA=getCoordinatefromIndices(nodes[i].indices[j].x).xyz;
                    vec3 TrianglePointB=getCoordinatefromIndices(nodes[i].indices[j].y).xyz;
                    vec3 TrianglePointC=getCoordinatefromIndices(nodes[i].indices[j].z).xyz;

                    hitreal=rayTriangleIntersect(ray, TrianglePointA, TrianglePointB, TrianglePointC);

                    if (hitreal.t==-1){ continue; }

                    if (hitreal.t>0 && (besthit.t>hitreal.t || besthit.t<0)){
                        besthit=hitreal;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (nodes[i].leftOrRight==0){
                i=i+1;
                continue;
            }

            else if (nodes[i].leftOrRight==1){

                int id=int(ceil(i-2)/2);
                FlatBvhNode parent=nodes[id];

                while (parent.leftOrRight==1){
                    parent=nodes[int(ceil(parent.order-2)/2)];
                    if (parent.order==0){
                        return besthit;
                    }
                }
                i = parent.order+1;
                continue;
            }
        }


        hit = rayIntersectWithBox(nodes[i].min, nodes[i].max, ray);

        if (hit) {

            if (nodes[i].isLeaf==0){
                i=2*i+1;
                continue;
            }
        }

        else {

            if (nodes[i].order==0){
                break;
            }


            if (nodes[i].leftOrRight==0) {
                i=i+1;
                continue;
            }

           node-nál vagyunk.
            else if (nodes[i].leftOrRight==1){
                FlatBvhNode parent=nodes[int(ceil(i-2)/2)];

                while (parent.leftOrRight==1){
                    parent=nodes[int(ceil(parent.order-2)/2)];
                    if (parent.order==0){
                        if (parent.order==0){
                            return besthit;
                        }
                    }
                }
                i = parent.order+1;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    return besthit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm in `rayIntersectWithBox` seems to be wrong.

The ray intersects the box, if the minimum is less than the maximum, for all 3 dimensions separately
Furthermore, you have to consider the direction of the ray. That means you have to evaluate the minimum and maximum dependent on the *sign* of the component of the direction  vector (`sign(invdir)`).

I suggest:

```c
bool rayIntersectWithBox(const vec4 boxMin, const vec4 boxMax, const Ray r) {
    vec3 invdir = 1.0 / r.dir.xyz;
    const vec3 f = (boxMax.xyz - r.orig.xyz) * invdir;
    const vec3 n = (boxMin.xyz - r.orig.xyz) * invdir;

    const vec3 tmax = f * sign(invdir);
    const vec3 tmin = n * sign(invdir);

    return tmin.x < tmax.x && tmin.y < tmax.y && tmin.z < tmax.z;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it is the same as in the last picture. I guess there is something wrong with the bvh-tree travelsal method as well.

Comment: To be more accurate, your solution fixed the bounding box issue, but for a reason there is only one triangle.